# update the package body in Oracle Database (Sql developer)

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to have a miner update to the package body in Oracle Database  using Oracle SQL Deverloper 3.2. The update does not need to change the package specification.

Using the Oracle SQL Deverloper, I right-click on the package name, choose "edit body", then update the body.

Then I find that it seems there are several ways to update the package body:

(1) click "run" button.

(2) click "compile" button.

(3) click "compile with debug" button.

(4) close the tab of package windows, then choose "yes" to save the changes on the pop-up windows.

My questions are:

1) what are the difference in the above 4 ways?

2) which is the proper way?

Thanks a lot

Regards

Answer (score 4):

1) When you click "Run", the SQL Developer starts to execute the current Active SQL. And now it is a `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE...`, so it turns to be a DDL

2) When you click Compile, Developer explicitly do the same as previous. No difference actually.

3) When you choose for Debug, if you enable "debugger" in SQL Developer, then you can enable breakpoints in your code, after compiling.

4) When you click Save, SQL Developer simply pushes the code to be Executed, again as Step1.

All are proper ways, but when you SQL developer to edit your proc, you may feel some slowness, because it do maintain some persistent setting behind the screens, and it is slightly buggy. It wont harm, but just slows down.